# Вывести результат массива по клику

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, json

Не получается вывести информацию массива по клику. Выводится пустой массив хотя информация там есть .  Я пытался словить событие клик по виртуальной клавиши ентер, и запихнуть туда console.log c результатом массива. Но возвращается 0.
Хотя тот же конслол но без события клик дает результат.

Вот так работает :`console.log(scope.masiive)`

А так нет : `$(".enter").click(function() { console.log(scope.masiive)}`

Мои предположения, что массив очищается до того как происходит клик по виртуальной клавише. Но сделать как надо не получается. Подскажите , что я делаю неправильно.

Вот код :

```
        open: function(event, ui) {
         var scope = this;
       this.masiive = []; // Очищаем массив 
          $("li").click(function() {
       alert($("li[data-context-key]").attr("data-context-key"))
     });
   },

 create: function() {
   var scope = this;
   scope .masiive = [];
        $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
      scope.masiive.push(item.value); // Добавляем значения
        alert(scope.masiive)
          return $('<li>').attr("data-context-key", item.value)
            .append(item.label)
            .appendTo(ul);

   };
  }

       });
   });
```

Код для демонстрации проблемы (если нажать клавишу "л" выведится результат массива, нужно так же но при нажатии на виртуальную клавишу "ентер" ) :     http://jsfiddle.net/t52ka/118/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас проблема с областью видимости переменной.
Вынесите `scope.masiive` в глобальную переменную. Например используйте везде `window.scope.masiive`. **Но** использование глобальных переменных крайне не желательно. Почитайте на эту тему, например [Хабр](http://habrahabr.ru/post/127482/)

Comment: вынес но всё равно возвращается , пустой...

Comment: значит где-то вы его обнуляете, например здесь `this.masiive = []; // Очищаем массив`